# LevelDB and IndexedDB: maximum key size? Like, how many characters long the key could be

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, leveldb

How long can a key of these key-value databases - IndexedDB (in-browser) and LevelDB (on server) be?

(I'm failing to find this figure online and in the docs.)

From a relational database experience I can imagine that the indexing routine might need the keys to be relatively short in order to sort them effectively

Comment: Also https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#key-construct

Comment: Thank you, the first link does, will explore more of the second link, at least I can't yet see any constraints too! Which is promising.